# How/where can I find paying clients?

Tags: business

I've been a graphic artist since 2002. Since then, I've had a difficult time finding paying clients to the point that I changed careers. However, I missed working as a graphic artist and got back into it recently. However, I've encountered the same challenges this time around.

I'm wondering how and where can I find paying clients online? I've tried Craigslist, DeviantArt, eLance, etc. I'm wondering which sites other designers have successfully found paying clients on.

Comment: How's your portfolio?

Comment: We have a lot of questions similar: ["Where can I find web design projects?"](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/27525/where-can-i-find-web-design-projects)

Comment: My portfolio is extensive. I have display ads for several luxury car manufacturers and album/book covers for several labels/publishers. I have worked professionally as a Creative Director and Art Executive. I also have a BFA and have been accepted for my MFA.

Comment: Hi there! I marked this one as duplicate because you mentioned Elance, but if you DON'T want freelance sites then you can edit this question (or create a new one) and make it more about how to find bigger clients, or long term clients, or something like that.